# EditText does not show the text

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my test application I have a activity with some fragments. When the user select a item from a fragment, the item is loaded on another fragment.

But the edittext of the fragment does not show the text setted before. If I print a log with its getText the text is printed. But in de screen the edittext is empty.

Just for a test, I change the color of the text and the backgroud together with the text. But I can not see any diference.

The code where I set the new values:

```
private void initValues(GeneralInformation generalInformation) {

    clientSalesOrderNumberEdit.setText(generalInformation.clientSalesOrderNumber);
    representativeSalesOrderNumberEdit.setText(generalInformation.representativeSalesOrderNumber);
    salesOrderNoteEdit.setText(generalInformation.salesOrderNote);
    revenueNoteEdit.setText(generalInformation.revenueNote);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sales_order_general_fragment);

    salesOrderEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_id);
    salesOrderTypeEdit = (InstantAutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_type);
    emissionDateText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_emission);
    baseDateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_base);
    revenueAntecipatedEdit = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_revenue_antecipated);
    clientSalesOrderNumberEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_number_client);
    representativeSalesOrderNumberEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_number_representative);
    salesChannelTypeEdit = (InstantAutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_sales_channel);
    salesOrderNoteEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_note);
    revenueNoteEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.sales_order_general_revenue_note);

    salesOrderNoteEdit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(250) });
    revenueNoteEdit.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(250) });

    salesOrderEdit.setEnabled(false);
    emissionDateText.setEnabled(false);

    GeneralInformation generalInformation = ((SalesOrderGeneralActivity)getActivity()).getSalesOrderGeneralInfo();

    updateEnabled(((SalesOrderGeneralActivity)getActivity()).isDraft());

    initValues(generalInformation);

    Button btnGeral = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_lateral_btn_geral);
    btnGeral.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btnCliente = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_lateral_btn_cliente);
    btnCliente.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btnTransportePagamento = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_lateral_btn_transporte_pagamento);
    btnTransportePagamento.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btnIncluirItem = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_lateral_btn_add_item);
    btnIncluirItem.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button btnListItens = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_lateral_btn_list_itens);
    btnListItens.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnGeral.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_lateral_ativado_geral);
    btnGeral.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lateral_menu_text_selected));

    return this.view;
}
```

If I set a text explicit like:

```
salesOrderNoteEdit.setText("fooooo");
```

It's works, the string is showed

Any tip?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please can you provide some code with your question, it will help locate any issues. Thanks

Comment: Please post your code of "another fragment". It seems to be a simple mistake.